# Can you put breaks in a string literal?

Tags: c++, newline

This is a constant I am using, it is split like this because I did not want to have to scroll my editor

```
const string PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION = "Program will calculate the amount "
"accumulated every month you save, until you reach your goal.";

int main() 
{
    cout << PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION;
    return 0;
}
```

Currently prints out in command prompt as

```
Program will calculate the amount accumulated every month you save,until you re
ach your goal.
```

When this prints out I would like it to print on two separate lines like below...

```
Program will calculate the amount accumulated every month you save,
until you reach your goal.
```

I do not know where to put break statements in a string so I can get it to print out correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using a `\n` to insert a newline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just insert a `\n` character to force a new line

```
const string PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION = "Program will calculate the amount "
"accumulated every month you save, \nuntil you reach your goal.";
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I had tried to add /n, but mine had a space after the "n" which then made it appear in the string

Comment: Well something is missing. Clue, imagine it is Windows OS and created form applicaton, not console.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\n` at the end of the first part of the literal for that, like this:

```
const string PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION = "Program will calculate the amount\n"
"accumulated every month you save, until you reach your goal."; //   ^^
```

You do not have to split the literal into parts if you do not wish to do so for readability:

```
const string PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION = "Program will calculate the amount accumulated every month you save,\nuntil you reach your goal.";
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can use a raw string literal

```
const char* stuff =
R"foo(this string
is for real)foo";
std::cout << stuff;
```

outputs:

```
this string
is for real
```

(I put this answer here for pedantic reasons, use \n)

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` in the string where you want the line to break.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a line break "\n" in the position you want in your const string, as you would do in a normal literal string:

```
const string PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION = "Program will calculate the amount\naccumulated every month you save, until you reach your goal.";

cout << PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION;
```

Simple. Just the same way as you should me used to in using a literal string:

```
cout << "Program will calculate the amount\naccumulated every month you save, until you reach your goal.";
```

Right?

Answer (score 0):

Well answers are good, however my offer is to use `\r\n` for new line. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) some more, these two symbols should always work (unless you are using Atari 8-bit OS).

And some more explanation.

- `\n` - Line Feed. This should move printing pointer one line lower, but it may or may not set printing pointer to beginning o line.
- `\r` - Carriage Return. This sets line pointer at the beginning o line, and may or may not change line.
- `\r\n` - CR LF. Moves printing pointer to next line and sets it at the beginning of line.